# Can I use string for constant part of #define?

Tags: c

Can I use string for constant part of #define like this?

```
#define A string
```

if I can't, what can be alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. For instance,

```
#define MY_PATH "/path/to/file"
```

That defines a macro named `MY_PATH` which gets replaced during preprocessing by the string literal `"/path/to/file"`. Alternatively, a `const` global variable which type is `char` can be used. e.g. `char const* MY_PATH = "/path/to/file";`

Comment: Thanks! You are my hero!